# Clearing font cache in Electron app

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, electron

I'm developing an app using Electron. I'm trying to receive and react to a Windows broadcast message ([WM_FONTCHANGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145211(v=vs.85).aspx)). Is it actually possible somehow inside electron? With some extension maybe?

The other thing is to update the electron font cache. I add new fonts using [AddFontResource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183326(v=vs.85).aspx) and other apps are seeing the newly added font, so it works. But electron does not react, and does not see the added font. I tried relaunching it and clearing the cache, but no result. On the other hand, Chrome 47.0.2526.73 beta-m (64-bit) sees the added fonts after a re-launch. I also tried this in Atom, and atom does not see the font.

So the question is: is Chrome using some method to clear the font cache of some sort? How can I achieve the same in electron? I will be glad to hear any suggestions.

**Update 1:** As I found out, the Windows broadcast message can be hooked using `win.hookWindowMessage(message, callback)` in Electron. That answers the first part of my question. Now I need to figure out how to update the font list.

Comment: What does this have to do with Node-Webkit? I don't see the connection?

Comment: Well, because Electron is almost the same as NW.js. So I figured maybe an answer that can be applied to NW.js can be applied here too.

Comment: While similar, they are not quite the same, for example, I haven't seen hookWindowMessage in NW.js at all, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: You may be right, I haven't had that much experience with NW.js.

Comment: No worries, it's just a bit confusing when the tags do not reflect the app in question, especially with things that are similar but not the same.  I've never used Electron for a project, so we are in the same boat.  I could not get win.hookWindowMessage to work in NW.js though.